# Проблема с Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx, android-manifest

На другом компьютере создал проект в libGDX. Платформы выбрал Android и Desktop. Создался совершенно обычный, тривиальный проект, ничего особенного. Работал в IntelliJ IDEA. Вот дерево:

[image: Дерево]

Скинул на его на гитхаб, и попробовал склонировать на другом компьютере. И тут начались ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модуль добавил руками, поменял пути, вроде всё корректно. Но и файлы с классами не работают и в манифесте ошибка. Как видно, манифест содержится не в самой папке с проектом, а подпапке его android, но сам манифест воспринимается вроде правильно. Я уже извёлся перебирать настройки. Что ни поставь в поле android:name, ни в какую не работает.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{by.randomen.attempt/by.randomen.attempt.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "by.randomen.attempt.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/by.randomen.attempt-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/by.randomen.attempt-2, /system/lib]]
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "by.randomen.attempt.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/by.randomen.attempt-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/by.randomen.attempt-2, /system/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
```

Comment: Проблема заключается у вас в том, что папка с Java файлами не рассматривается IDE как папка с исходниками. Вроде, где-то в настройках проекта можно указать определённые папки как папки с исходниками. Тогда IDE будет там искать файлы и при обработке манифеста найдёт ваш класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственным решение проблемы транспортировки проекта с устройства на устройство оказалось размещение конфигурационных файлов из каталога .idea/. Это не совсем корректно, однако, это необходимо, чтобы проект успешно заработал на другом компьютере.